# function to check if there is any empty cell in a multicolumn nstableview not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

Hi i have written a function to check if there is any empty cell in a multicolumn nstableview like below.However this function is not working and always checks for the columns in the first row only.. any suggestions.and what is the right way to check for it

```
  -(BOOL)isTableRowsContainingEmptyCells
    {



        for(int row=0;row< [[self.myarray arrangedObjects] count];row++)
        {
        NSTableColumn *column1 = [self.formFieldValues
                                  tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"A"];
        NSTableColumn *column2 = [self.formFieldValues
                                  tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"B"];
        NSCell *cell1 = [column1 dataCellForRow:row];
        NSCell *cell2 = [column2 dataCellForRow:row];
            NSLog(@"cell1 %@ cell2 %@",cell1,cell2);
        if([[cell1 stringValue] isEqualToString:@""]||[cell1 stringValue]==nil||[[cell2 stringValue] isEqualToString:@""]||[cell2 stringValue]==nil)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't use numberOfRows of the controller itself instead of something arrays? I mean this part: [[self.myarray arrangedObjects] count]

Comment: because ultimately this array itself is the tableviews datasource...both are correct

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
NSCell *cll=[tableView preparedCellAtColumn:0 row:0];
            NSString *str=[cll stringValue];
NSInteger len=[str length];
if (len ==0)
{
    NSLog(@"NO data")
}
```